# Worklight https adapter call "https refused"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Could not able to get response from HTTPS Adapter call .
My code as follows

```
     <connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>my domain</domain>

         <port>443</port>

        <sslCertificateAlias>MRDSE</sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword>testpwd</sslCertificatePassword>
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>
```

Getting error as 
          ""errors": [
      "Runtime: Http request failed: javax net SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"
   ],"

I Have also mentioned in work light properties

```
       ssl.keystore.path=conf/rc.keystore
       ssl.keystore.type=jks
       ssl.keystore.password=mypwd
```

Please suggest to get HTTPS response

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the certificate in the keystore?

Also, please refer to this answer to an almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914147/2245921