# IBM Worklight adapter - https backend peer not authenticated

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, ibm-was

I was trying to connect to a https back end service from the Worklight adapters in my local pc for the my app.

But I was getting the below error, then I posted a question [Making web service calls to a HTTPS server from Worklight Adapter - javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905150/making-web-service-calls-to-a-https-server-from-worklight-adapter-javax-net-ss)

```
Runtime: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

I followed the steps given here

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_ibm_worklight_server_and_self-signed_certificates.html

and imported a self signed certificate in the java cacerts keystore of my system and the adapters started working. Wow!!!

Now, I have deployed my adapters over a WAS and followed the same steps, imported the certificate there also, but I am still getting the error when I try to use the adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that WAS has its own JRE with its own keystore that needs to be updated.
Also, if you're using recent release of WL the usage of self signed certificates within WL adapters became much simpler - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how to updated the certificate in keystore referenced by WAS or where is it actually located?

Comment: look for JRE folder inside of your WAS installation